# Delete email after read in S22.IMAP

Tags: c#-4.0, gmail-imap

I want to delete email after download of attachment. I have write code to 
download email attachment but i don't know how to delete email.

In this i have use S22.Imap Namespace to read gmail email and download email attachment.

So anybody know how to delete email from inbox or store to another folder.

```
 using S22.Imap;


 static void Main(string[] args)

 {

        const string username = "email"; 

        const string password = "password"; 

        ImapClient imap = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", 993, true, null);

        imap.Login(username, password, AuthMethod.Login);

        if(imap.Authed)

        {
            IEnumerable<string> mailbox = imap.ListMailboxes();

            IEnumerable<uint> allMailsID = 

            imap.Search(SearchCondition.All(),"INBOX");

            IEnumerable<MailMessage> allMails = imap.GetMessages(allMailsID, 

            true, "INBOX");

            string filePath = string.Format(@"D:\Folders\InputFolder\");

            foreach (MailMessage mail in allMails)

            {     

                AttachmentCollection attachColl = mail.Attachments;

                if(attachColl.Count > 0)

                {

                    foreach (var item in attachColl)

                    {

                        //Console.WriteLine("Name :"+ item.Name);

                        string date = 

            Convert.ToDateTime(mail.Headers["Date"]).ToShortDateString(); 

                        CopyStream(item.ContentStream, (filePath +          
  item.Name));         

                    }

                }

            }

        }


        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void CopyStream(Stream stream, string destPath)
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(destPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }       

    }
```

Comment: If you are just needing to delete a message, then you can use the method [`Users.messages: delete`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/delete). Immediately and permanently deletes the specified message. This operation cannot be undone. Prefer `messages.trash` instead.